# Getting field name of uploaded file

Tags: php, upload

I'm writing a class to manage uploded files. Since the field name from the form the file is uploaded form can't be known now, here is what I'm doing:

```
        $field_name = array_keys($_FILES)[0];
```

Is that safe? Can I trust that the first key in $_FILES will always be the field name from the form?
Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only the one `<input type="file"... />` tag in your form yes. If there is more than one then the index 1 will be the second one etc.

Comment: Oh, I get it, so I may have to add a foreach loop in case there is more than one file. Thanks!